# Autoload Mapping for modules

Tags: 8, composer

I'm trying to better understand how Drupal 8 autoloading for classes is automatically mapped to the *src* directory in modules.

Basically, I'd like to know how the system knows to look in the *modules/module_name/srс* directory when searching for classes.

I can't seem to find any details on how it's done through the *composer.json* files or the *autoload_psr4.php* files. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drupal 8 follows [PSR 4 autoloading](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md) standard which is implemented by [composer autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

While some Drupal namespaces are registered statically in *composer.json* and *core/composer.json* other namespaces are processed dynamically ([see *DrupalKernel::classLoaderAddMultiplePsr4*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21DrupalKernel.php/function/DrupalKernel%3A%3AclassLoaderAddMultiplePsr4/8.2.x)).

[PSR-4 namespaces and autoloading in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8)

Comment: Ya.teck, thank you for the reply. I looked through that file for the calssLoaderAddMultiplePsr4 and found myself in the DrupalKernal::discoverServiceproviders method.

Am I correct in saying those two methods together work to register the module namespaces and mapping to the src/ directory dynamically for all enabled modules?

Comment: It looks they do so.